# Keep Bootstrap dropdown button focused when even if clicked on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem keeping bootstrap dropdown button focused when clicked(:focus) on the input field inside the dropdown.

```html
<div id="select_btn">
                        <div class="btn-group">
             
                            <button class="btn btn-custom-select btn-group show-properties dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                <span class="select-p-text">Select a Property
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                <div id="propertyHolder">
                           
                                        <div class="right-inner-addon">
                                           
                                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                            <input placeholder="Search for a property..." id="box" type="search" />
                                             
                                  
                                        </div>
                                     <li role="separator" class="divider"></li></div>
                                    <li><ul class="selectList">
                    
                                    </ul>
                                     </li>
                                </div>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Comment: so, how could people would understand your problem if you do not give any sample codes?

Comment: @manetsus added sample code